# How to disable HTTP TRACE on OpenBSD 5.3?

Tags: openbsd, apache-httpd, openbsd-httpd

An nmap scan gaved this:

```
443/tcp  open     ssl/http Apache httpd
| http-methods: GET HEAD OPTIONS TRACE
| Potentially risky methods: TRACE
|_See http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/http-methods.html
```

so I tried to:

```
# DISABLE TRACE
vi /var/www/conf/httpd.conf
TraceEnable off
```

**Q:** But it gaved syntax error. How can I securely disable Trace HTTP METHOD on OpenBSD 5.3?

p.s.: Why is an insecure option enabled in a secure OS?

Comment: Regarding that “insecure option”, the `httpd` documentation says “Despite claims to the contrary, TRACE is not a security vulnerability and there is no viable reason for it to be disabled.”

Comment: Show us where exactly you inserted that directive and paste the exact error message.